# Plot the complete to one loss function

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, neural-network, loss-function

When I plot the loss function of my code I get a nice loss plot.
If I want to plot the `1-hist.history['loss']`, how can I do it?
Part of my code:

```
model = Sequential([
    Dense(32, activation='relu', input_shape=(2,)),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='relu'), ])

model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
             loss='mean_squared_error')

hist = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
                 batch_size=32, epochs=100,
                 validation_data=(X_val, Y_val))

A = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)[1]
print(A)  

plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(hist.history['val_loss'])
plt.title('Model loss')
plt.ylabel('Loss')
plt.xlabel('Epoch')
plt.legend(['Train', 'Val'], loc='upper right')
plt.savefig("loss.png")  # Save the plot of loss function
plt.clf()
```

In this part of the code: `plt.plot(hist.history['loss'])` I want to change it to the number that complete to 1.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to try in case `hist` is a pandas dataframe:

```py
complete_to_one = 1 - hist.history['loss'])
plt.plot(complete_to_one)
```